# Removing tailing tabs from a string column in a Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to clean a column from a Dataframe which contains tailing whitespaces. Something like this:

```
'17063256          '
'17403492                                            '
'17390052                                   '
```

First, I tried to remove white spaces using `trim`:

```
df.withColumn("col1_cleansed", trim(col("col1")))
```

Then I though it may be tailing "tabs", so I tried as well with:

```
df.withColumn("col1_cleansed", regexp_replace(col("col1"), "\t", ""))
```

However none of these two solutions seems to be working.

What is the correct way to remove "tab" characters from a string column in Spark?

Comment: i think its not tabs or spaces. can you please post actual data

Comment: @Srinivas The example I provided is actual data. I will add a few more. As you can see they aren't even constant in length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `trim` or `rtrim` does seem to have problem handling general whitespaces.  To remove trailing whitespaces, consider using `regexp_replace` with regex pattern `\\s+$` (with '$' representing end of string), as shown below:

```
val df = Seq(
  "17063256 ",     // space
  "17403492 ",     // tab
  "17390052     "  // space + tab
).toDF("c1")

df.withColumn("c1_trimmed", regexp_replace($"c1", "\\s+$", "")).show

// Output (prettified)
// +------------+----------+
// |          c1|c1_trimmed|
// +------------+----------+
// |   17063256 |  17063256|
// | 17403492   |  17403492|
// |17390052    |  17390052|
// +------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach is working perfectly. As an extra, in case I would like to use the same solution but for both leading and tailing ws, how would it be the regex? "^\\s+$"?

Comment: To remove both leading and trailing whitespaces, the regex pattern can be "^\\s+|\\s+$", with '|' representing an 'or'.

Answer (score 1):

Try below `udf` & change as per your needs.

```
val normalize = udf((in: String) => {
      import java.text.Normalizer.{normalize ⇒ jnormalize, _}
      val cleaned = in.trim.toLowerCase
      val normalized = jnormalize(cleaned, Form.NFD).replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsM}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+", "")

      normalized.replaceAll("'s", "")
        .replaceAll("ß", "ss")
        .replaceAll("ø", "o")
        .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9-]+", " ")
    })
```

```
df.withColumn("col1_cleansed", normalize(col("col1")))
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can `regex_replace` to and replace with `""`

```
df.withColumn("new", regexp_replace($"id", " ",""))
.show(false)
```

Output:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|id                                                    |new       |
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|'17063256          '                                  |'17063256'|
|'17403492                                            '|'17403492'|
|'17390052                                   '         |'17390052'|
+------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but that one is not working. It´s like the characters were not detected as ws, that is why I was suspecting that may be tabs instead

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the problem. Extract only the required portion from the column .This will work if you are expecting only alphanumeric values and nothing else.
Feel free to modify it to accept numbers only if required.

`df.withColumn("cleansed_col",regexp_extract(col("input"),"[a-z0-9]+",0))`